# Julia Fractal Drawing in C++

Tags: c++, performance, image, fractals, openmp

I'd like a code review for this program written to draw [Julia fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set). I'm specifically looking for feedback on:

- **Style**: I haven't written much C++ before, so I'm interested in knowing better or more idiomatic ways of formatting or structuring my code.
- **Performance**: Am I doing anything that's needlessly slowing down my program, or that I could optimize out?

## julia.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <omp.h>

#include <png++/png.hpp>

// defining a few constants
#define MAX_ITERATIONS 2000
#define XPIXELS 1920
#define YPIXELS 1080

typedef std::complex<double> complex;

// code for this taken from
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865668/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c
class InputParser {
public:
    InputParser(int& argc, char **argv) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
            this->tokens.push_back(std::string(argv[i]));
        }
    }

    const std::string& getCmdOption(const std::string& option) const{
        std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter;
        iter = std::find(this->tokens.begin(), this->tokens.end(), option);
        if (iter != this->tokens.end() && ++iter != this->tokens.end()) {
            return *iter;
        }
        static const std::string empty_string("");
        return empty_string;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> getCmdOptionN(const std::string& option, int n) const{
        std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter;
        std::vector<std::string> results;
        std::vector<std::string> empty_vec;
        iter = std::find(this->tokens.begin(), this->tokens.end(), option);
        if (iter == this->tokens.end()) {
            return empty_vec;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
            if (iter+i != this->tokens.end()) {
                results.push_back(*(iter+i));
            } else {
                return empty_vec;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    bool cmdOptionExists(const std::string& option) const{
        return std::find(this->tokens.begin(), this->tokens.end(), option) != this->tokens.end();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
};

// struct representing vectors in R^3
// along with some basic operations on them
struct Vec3 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    Vec3() {}
    Vec3(double xx, double yy, double zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {}
    
    Vec3 operator+(const Vec3& v) {
        return Vec3(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z);
    }

    Vec3 operator-(const Vec3& v) {
        return Vec3(x-v.x, y-v.y, z-v.z);
    }

    Vec3 operator*(double& a) {
        return Vec3(a*x, a*y, a*z);
    }

    Vec3 operator/(double& a) {
        return Vec3(x/a, y/a, z/a);
    }
    
    bool operator==(const Vec3& v) {
        return x == v.x && y == v.y && z == v.z;
    }

    void print() {
        std:: cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")\n";
    }
    
    double dist(const Vec3& u, const Vec3& v) {
        return sqrt((u.x - v.x)*(u.x - v.x) +
                (u.y - v.y)*(u.y - v.y) +
                (u.z - v.z)*(u.z - v.z));
    }
};

Vec3 operator*(double& a, const Vec3& v)
{
    return Vec3(a*v.x, a*v.y, a*v.z);
};

// counts the number of iterations it takes for a complex function `f(z) = z^power + c0` evaluated iteratively
// at an initial point `init` to grow greater than 2 in magnitude
// normalized to achieve smoother coloring, look at this webpage for details:
// http://linas.org/art-gallery/escape/escape.html
double normalized_iterations(complex init, complex c0, int power)
{
    complex z = init;
    int iters = 0;
    while ((abs(z) <= 2) && (iters < MAX_ITERATIONS)) {
        z = std::pow(z,power) + c0;
        iters += 1;
    }
    double mu = iters;
    if ( iters < MAX_ITERATIONS ) {
        mu = iters + 1 - log(log(abs(z))) / log(power);
    }
    return mu;
}

// computes v + t(u - v)
// t should be a value between 0 and 1
Vec3 linear_interpolation(Vec3& v, Vec3& u, double t)
{
    return v + t*(u - v);
}

// creates a linear gradient of SIZE colours, using RGB values from PTS
// interspersed evenly
std::vector<Vec3> linear_interpolated_gradient(std::vector<Vec3> pts, int size)
{
    std::vector<Vec3> pal;
    int to_travel = size;
    int lines_left = pts.size();
    int pts_to_color;
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size()-1; i++) {
        if (to_travel % lines_left != 0) {
            pts_to_color = (to_travel / lines_left)+1;
        } else {
            pts_to_color = to_travel / lines_left;
        }
        to_travel = to_travel - pts_to_color;
        lines_left--;
        double scaling = 1.0 / pts_to_color;
        Vec3 delta_vec = scaling*(pts[i+1] - pts[i]);
        Vec3 next_color = pts[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < pts_to_color; j++) {
            pal.push_back(next_color);
            next_color = next_color + delta_vec;
        }
    }
    return pal;
}
    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::string& usage = "Usage: -f <filename> [-p <power>] -c <real_part> <imag_part> [-origin <x> <y>] [-z <zoom>] [-verbose]\nPower defaults to 2, origin defaults to (0,0)\n";

    // Parsing command line arguments
    InputParser input(argc, argv);
    const std::string& filename = input.getCmdOption("-f");
    if (filename.empty()) {
        std::cout << usage;
        return 0;
    }
    
    const std::string& power_string = input.getCmdOption("-p");
    int power = 2;
    if (!power_string.empty()) {
        power = stoi(power_string);
    }
    
    const std::vector<std::string>& complex_strings = input.getCmdOptionN("-c", 2);
    if (complex_strings.empty()) {
        std::cout << usage;
        return 0;
    }
    const double real_part = stod(complex_strings[0]);
    const double imag_part = stod(complex_strings[1]);

    double origin_x = 0.0, origin_y = 0.0;
    const std::vector<std::string>& origin_strings = input.getCmdOptionN("-origin", 2);
    if (!origin_strings.empty()) {
        origin_x = stod(origin_strings[0]);
    origin_y = stod(origin_strings[1]);
    }

    double zoom = 1.0;
    const std::string& zoom_string = input.getCmdOption("-z");
    if (!zoom_string.empty()) {
        zoom = stod(zoom_string);
    }
    
    bool verbose = input.cmdOptionExists("-verbose");

    // Setting up parameters
    const complex complex_constant(real_part, imag_part);

    // computing C -> pixel mapping
    double im_start = origin_y + 1.08/zoom;
    double re_start = origin_x - 1.92/zoom;
    double delta_y = 2*1.08/zoom / YPIXELS, delta_x = 2*1.92/zoom / XPIXELS;
    double im, re;

    if (verbose) {
        std::cout << "im_start = " << im_start << "\nre_start = " << re_start << std::endl;
        std::cout << "delta_y = " << delta_y << "\ndelta_x = " << delta_x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "zoom = " << zoom << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Running on " << omp_get_max_threads() << " threads" << std::endl;
    }

    // another thing that would be nice to add is allow the user to input a file
    // consisting of RGB triples to set up the color palette with
    std::vector<Vec3> colors;
    colors.push_back(Vec3(0, 0, 0));
    colors.push_back(Vec3(213, 67, 31));
    colors.push_back(Vec3(251, 255, 121));  
    colors.push_back(Vec3(62, 223, 89));
    colors.push_back(Vec3(43, 30, 218));
    colors.push_back(Vec3(0, 255, 247));
    
    std::vector<Vec3> palette = linear_interpolated_gradient(colors, 100);
    png::image<png::rgb_pixel> image(XPIXELS, YPIXELS);
 
    #pragma omp parallel for private(re) private(im)
    for (int y = 0; y < YPIXELS; y++) {
        if (verbose) {
            std::cout << "Computing row " << y+1 << '/' << YPIXELS << "...\n";
        }
        im = im_start - y*delta_y;
        for (int x = 0; x < XPIXELS; x++) {
            re = re_start + x*delta_x;
            complex init(re,im);
            double mu = normalized_iterations(init, complex_constant, power);
            // scale mu to be in the range of 1-100
            mu *= 100.0/MAX_ITERATIONS;
            double tmp;
            Vec3 color1 = palette[(int)floor(mu)];
            Vec3 color2 = palette[(int)ceil(mu)];
            Vec3 color = linear_interpolation(color1, color2, modf(mu, &tmp));
            image[y][x] = png::rgb_pixel(color.x, color.y, color.z);
        }
    }
    image.write(filename);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify which compiler/libraries you are using? `<omp.h>` and `<png++/png.hpp>` are not standard headers.

Comment: I'm using g++ 5.4.0 for compiling. `<omp.h>` is the header for the openMP multiprocessing API (supported by gcc and a bunch of other compilers). `<png++/png.hpp>` is from png++, a C++ wrapper for libpng.

Comment: What's a good set of arguments to this program, to get a good representative output?  I'm no expert on Julia sets, and the options seem a little arbitrary.

Comment: I found on Wikipedia `-c -0.8 +0.156` (with default zoom) gives something to work with.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Unqualified names

The namespace identifier is missing from a lot of names - e.g. `std::sqrt`, `std::log`, `std::abs`, `std::stoi`, `std::stod`.  It's not portable to rely on the unqualified names being defined.

## Input parser

A lot of this is unnecessarily verbose.  There's no need to write `this->tokens` all the time when `tokens` is perfectly clear.  For example, I'd write its constructor as

```
InputParser(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        tokens.emplace_back(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

I've changed `argc` to be `int` rather than `int&`, and constructed the strings in-place in the vector.

`getCmdOption` could benefit from using `auto` to declare the iterator (and I'm not convinced the long name helps - it's obviously getting from command arguments because its a member of our arguments object):

```
const std::string& optionValue(const std::string& option) const
{
    static const std::string not_found{};
    auto it = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), option);
    return it != tokens.end() && ++it != tokens.end() ? *it : not_found;
}
```

---

This gives:

```
class InputParser
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens = {};

public:
    InputParser(int argc, char **argv) {
        for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) tokens.emplace_back(argv[i]);
    }

    const std::string& optionValue(const std::string& option) const
    {
        static const std::string not_found{};
        auto it = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), option);
        return it != tokens.end() && ++it != tokens.end() ? *it : not_found;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> optionValues(const std::string& option, int n) const
    {
        static const std::vector<std::string> not_found{};
        auto it = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), option);
        if (std::distance(it, tokens.end()) <= n) return not_found;

        std::vector<std::string> results;
        results.reserve(n);
        while (n--) results.push_back(*++it);
        return results;
    }

    bool contains(const std::string& option) const
    {
        return std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), option) != tokens.end();
    }
};
```

## Vector

The `Vec3D` class misses some of the obvious operators you might need in future (`+=`, `/=`, etc), but you can add them when you need them.  The default memberwise `==` would be the same as what you've written, so you don't actually need `==` or `!=`.  But they aren't very useful anyway, as comparing floating-point values for equality doesn't usually work as we want.

The operators that we do have can all be declared `const` (and accept `double` arguments by value rather than by reference).

The `print()` method is unconventional - we normally write that as:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vec3& v)
{
    return os << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << ")\n";
}
```

The `dist()` method isn't using `this` - we could make it static, or remove one of the arguments.  I'd write a no-argument form, and use that for the two-argument one:

```
double dist() const {
    return std::hypot(std::hypot(x, y), z);
}
double dist(const Vec3& other) const {
    return (*this - other).dist();
}
```

(`std::hypot()` is better behaved and optimised than hand-writing Pythagoras' formula)

---

This gives:

```
struct Vec3 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    Vec3() : Vec3(0, 0, 0) {}
    Vec3(double xx, double yy, double zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {}

    Vec3 operator+(const Vec3& v) const {
        return Vec3(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z);
    }

    Vec3 operator-(const Vec3& v) const {
        return Vec3(x-v.x, y-v.y, z-v.z);
    }

    Vec3 operator*(double a) const {
        return Vec3(a*x, a*y, a*z);
    }

    Vec3 operator/(double a) const {
        return Vec3(x/a, y/a, z/a);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vec3& v)
    {
        return os << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << ")\n";
    }

    double dist() const {
        return std::hypot(std::hypot(x, y), z);
    }
    double dist(const Vec3& other) const {
        return (*this - other).dist();
    }
};

Vec3 operator*(double a, const Vec3& v)
{
    return Vec3(a*v.x, a*v.y, a*v.z);
}
```

Having written all this, I later discovered that we were only using this class for interpolating pixel values (see later in answer), and it got excised from my final version.

## Counting iterations

It's going to be a bit more efficient to compute the squared magnitude of `z` than its absolute value: `std::norm(z) <= 4`.  I'd write the counting loop as a `for` loop like this:

```
double normalized_iterations(complex z, complex c0, int power)
{
    int iters;
    for (iters = 0;  std::norm(z) <= 4;  ++iters) {
        if (iters == MAX_ITERATIONS) return iters;
        z = std::pow(z,power) + c0;
    }
    return iters + 1 - std::log(std::log(std::abs(z))) / std::log(power);
}
```

Or even

```
double normalized_iterations(complex z, const complex c0, const int power)
{
    int iters;
    for (iters = 0;  std::norm(z) <= 4;  z = std::pow(z,power) + c0) {
        if (++iters == MAX_ITERATIONS) return iters;
    }
    return iters + 1 - std::log(std::log(std::abs(z))) / std::log(power);
}
```

You might consider writing your own `pow(complex, int)` and testing to see whether that's more efficient than `std::pow(complex, double)`.  Search for "**binary exponentiation**" for an outline of the algorithm (and remember that negative powers are just the reciprocals of the corresponding positive ones).

## Colour interpolation

I struggled to follow the logic of `linear_interpolated_gradient()`.  However, the good news is that we don't need it at all.  We were using it to generate a 100-colour palette from an initial 6-colour palette, but then we were using that 100-colour palette to *interpolate an output colour*.  We can interpolate directly from the 6-colour palette and save all that.

Further, repurposing `Vec3` to represent colours is misleading.  Let's work with `png::rgb_pixel` directly:

```
static const std::vector<png::rgb_pixel> colors{
    {  0,   0,   0},
    {213,  67,  31},
    {251, 255, 121},
    { 62, 223,  89},
    { 43,  30, 218},
    {  0, 255, 247}
};

png::rgb_pixel linear_interpolation(const png::rgb_pixel& v,
                                    const png::rgb_pixel& u, double a)
{
    auto const b = 1 - a;
    return png::rgb_pixel(b*v.red   + a*u.red,
                          b*v.green + a*u.green,
                          b*v.blue  + a*u.blue);
}
```

We'll then need to adjust the scaling for `mu` in `main()` to fit in `colors.size()` rather than `palette.size()` (which should have been written as 99, not 100 - a tricky off-by-one error).

## Options processing

The first part of `main()` examines the command-line arguments.  We do some checking, like this:

```
if (filename.empty()) {
    std::cout << usage;
    return 0;
}
```

We ought to print the usage to `std::cerr` and return non-zero to indicate failure.  Alternatively, we could make `-f` optional, and write to `std::cout` if a filename is not specified - that allows us to pipe into further processing (e.g. `pngcrush`).  It's probably a good idea to ensure we can write the file before spending time calculating - this is best done by opening the file at this point, and later using `png::image::write_stream()` to write the data:

```
std::ofstream outfile;
const std::string& filename = input.optionValue("-f");
std::ostream& out = filename.empty()
    ? std::cout
    : (outfile.open(filename, std::ios::out|std::ios::trunc|std::ios::binary), outfile);

if (!out) {
    perror(filename.c_str());
    return 1;
}

// ....

image.write_stream(out);
return 0;
```

We should leave opening the file until after checking the other arguments, so that we don't overwrite an existing file if we have to exit early with an error message.

## Calculating the domain

There's a couple of constants `1.92` and `1.08` whose origins aren't obvious.  I eventually reasoned that these are `XPIXELS / 1000.0` and `YPIXELS / 1000.0`  respectively.  We can change to make that more explicit:

```
auto const x_scale = .001 * XPIXELS / zoom;
auto const y_scale = .001 * YPIXELS / zoom;

const double im_start = origin_y + y_scale;
const double re_start = origin_x - x_scale;
const double delta = .002 / zoom;
```

(we don't need separate `delta_x` and `delta_y` - they evaluated to the same value).

## Logging output

The `verbose` output stream needs to go to `std::clog`, not `std::cout`.  That's necessary for pipelining to work.

## Reduce scope of pixel position

We can move `im` and `re` into the `for` loop, and avoid needing to declare them `private` to OpenMP.

## OpenMP scheduling

I thought that because rows have different computation times to each other, that `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)` might improve execution times.  But it seems that the overhead outweighs the benefit, in my testing.

---

## My version

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <omp.h>

#include <png++/png.hpp>

// defining a few constants - these should be user-specifiable
static constexpr auto max_iterations = 2000;
static constexpr auto width = 1920;
static constexpr auto height = 1080;

using complex = std::complex<double>;

class InputParser
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens = {};

public:
    InputParser(int argc, char **argv) {
        for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) tokens.emplace_back(argv[i]);
    }

    const std::string& optionValue(const std::string& option) const
    {
        static const std::string not_found{};
        auto it = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), option);
        return it != tokens.end() && ++it != tokens.end() ? *it : not_found;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> optionValues(const std::string& option, int n) const
    {
        static const std::vector<std::string> not_found{};
        auto it = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), option);
        if (std::distance(it, tokens.end()) <= n) return not_found;

        std::vector<std::string> results;
        results.reserve(n);
        while (n--) results.push_back(*++it);
        return results;
    }

    bool contains(const std::string& option) const
    {
        return std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), option) != tokens.end();
    }
};

// counts the number of iterations it takes for a complex function `f(z) = z^power + c0` evaluated iteratively
// at an initial point `init` to grow greater than 2 in magnitude
// normalized to achieve smoother coloring, look at this webpage for details:
// http://linas.org/art-gallery/escape/escape.html
double normalized_iterations(complex z, const complex c0, const int power)
{
    int iters;
    for (iters = 0;  std::norm(z) <= 4;  z = std::pow(z, power) + c0) {
        if (++iters == max_iterations) return 1;
    }
    return (iters + 1 - std::log(std::log(std::abs(z))) / std::log(power)) / max_iterations;
}

// computes v + t(u - v)
// t should be a value between 0 and 1
png::rgb_pixel linear_interpolation(const png::rgb_pixel& v, const png::rgb_pixel& u, double a)
{
    auto const b = 1 - a;
    return png::rgb_pixel(b*v.red   + a*u.red,
                          b*v.green + a*u.green,
                          b*v.blue  + a*u.blue);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static const auto usage =
        "Usage: -f <filename> [-p <power>] -c <real_part> <imag_part>"
        " [-origin <x> <y>] [-z <zoom>] [-verbose]\n"
        "Power defaults to 2, origin defaults to (0,0)\n";

    // Parsing command line arguments
    InputParser input(argc, argv);

    if (input.contains("-h") || input.contains("--help")) {
        std::cout << usage;
        return 0;
    }

    const bool verbose = input.contains("-verbose");
    const auto filename = input.optionValue("-f");
    const auto power_string = input.optionValue("-p");
    const auto complex_strings = input.optionValues("-c", 2);
    const auto origin_strings = input.optionValues("-origin", 2);

    int power = 2;
    if (!power_string.empty()) {
        power = std::stoi(power_string);
    }
    if (power < 2) {
        // a waste of time
        std::cerr << "Power must be at least 2" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (complex_strings.empty()) {
        std::cerr << usage;
        return 1;
    }
    const complex complex_constant{std::stod(complex_strings[0]),
                                   std::stod(complex_strings[1])};

    double origin_x = 0.0, origin_y = 0.0;
    if (!origin_strings.empty()) {
        origin_x = std::stod(origin_strings[0]);
        origin_y = std::stod(origin_strings[1]);
    }

    double zoom = 1.0;
    const auto zoom_string = input.optionValue("-z");
    if (!zoom_string.empty()) {
        zoom = std::stod(zoom_string);
    }

    std::ofstream outfile;
    std::ostream& out = filename.empty()
        ? std::cout
        : (outfile.open(filename, std::ios::out|std::ios::trunc|std::ios::binary), outfile);

    if (!out) {
        perror(filename.c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    // Julia set parameters
    auto const x_scale = .001 * width / zoom;
    auto const y_scale = .001 * height / zoom;

    const double im_start = origin_y + y_scale;
    const double re_start = origin_x - x_scale;
    const double delta = .002 / zoom;

    if (verbose) {
        std::clog << "im_start = " << im_start << "\nre_start = " << re_start << std::endl;
        std::clog << "delta = " << delta << std::endl;
        std::clog << "zoom = " << zoom << std::endl;
        std::clog << "Running on " << omp_get_max_threads() << " threads" << std::endl;
    }

    // Could we allow user input of these values?
    static const std::vector<png::rgb_pixel> colors{
        {  0,   0,   0},
        {213,  67,  31},
        {251, 255, 121},
        { 62, 223,  89},
        { 43,  30, 218},
        {  0, 255, 247}
    };
    static const auto max_color = colors.size() - 1;

    png::image<png::rgb_pixel> image(width, height);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int y = 0;  y < height;  y++) {
        if (verbose)
#pragma omp critical
        {
            std::clog << "Computing row " << y+1 << '/' << height << "...\n";
        }
        double im = im_start - y*delta;
        for (int x = 0;  x < width;  x++) {
            double re = re_start + x*delta;
            double mu = normalized_iterations({re,im}, complex_constant, power);
            // scale mu to be in the range of colors
            mu *= max_color;
            auto i_mu = static_cast<std::size_t>(mu);
            auto color1 = colors[i_mu];
            auto color2 = colors[std::min(i_mu+1, max_color)];
            image[y][x] = linear_interpolation(color1, color2, mu-i_mu);
        }
    }

    image.write_stream(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very impressive answer!

Comment: Good answer, but no mentioning of any `<Vector>::operator!=`/`==` is complete without also mentioning floating point inaccuracies and common methods of equality testing (e.g. fixed epsilon vs. scaled epsilon).

Comment: Fair enough @phresnel - I should have pointed out that the entire class disappeared in my final version when it was no longer being used for pixel interpolation.

Answer (score 14):

There's already a good answer, so I'm just going to raise a couple of small points.

I had the same thought as Toby Speight about saving the square root of `abs(z)`, but I would apply it also in the logarithm and avoid re-evaluating a known value. This may be taking micro-optimisation too far, but you can judge for yourself whether you think the hit to readability is too much to be worth it.

```
double normalized_iterations(complex z, const complex c0, const int power)
{
    int iters = 0;
    double norm = std::norm(z);
    for ( ; norm <= 4; norm = std::norm(z)) {
        if (++iters == MAX_ITERATIONS) return iters;
        z = std::pow(z, power) + c0;
    }
    return iters + 1 - std::log(0.5 * std::log(norm)) / std::log(power);
}
```

---

And this is a bit of a frame challenge. Linear interpolation in RGB creates muddy colours:

[image: RGB interpolation from green to red through muddy orange-brown]

Using a colour space which is designed to be closer to the way we perceive colours you can avoid the loss of vibrancy. E.g. with HSL, interpolating between the same endpoints:

[image: HSL interpolation from green to red through bright yellow]

HSL is probably a good compromise between speed and linear perception, although if you want to focus on interpolation quality over speed you could look into XYZ and L*a*b*.

Comment: Both excellent points. The png++ library we're using seems to have some colour-space conversions available, which might help with the interpolation.

Comment: Can use a lookup table (of length max_iterations) to precompute colour-space conversions and interpolations. Definitely interpolate in a perceptually-uniform colour space such as Lab or Luv (should at least try it and see how it looks).